# How to migrate from 2.0.0.RC2 spring batch version to 2.0.4?

Tags: java, xml, upgrade, spring-batch

I have to migrate my project from 2.0.0.RC2 version to 2.0.4. But the problem is the xsd of 2.0.4 is different then 2.0.0.RC2. That means none of my job configuration is going to work.

Job configuration in  2.0.0 RC2 was

```
<batch:job id="taskletComponentTestJob">
        <batch:step id="taskletTestComponent"
            tasklet="taskletForTestComponent">
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="customStepExecutionListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="customJobExecutionListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:job>
```

Job configuration in  2.0.4 will be

```
<batch:job id="taskletComponentTestJob1">
        <batch:step id="taskletTestComponent" >
            <batch:tasklet ref="taskletForTestComponent"> 
             </batch:tasklet>           
        </batch:step>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="customJobExecutionListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:job>
```

Is there any utility by which all my existing job configuration will become compatible to 2.0.4?
Also, after changing the configuration will i face any further problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any utility by which all my existing job configuration will become compatible to 2.0.4?

I doubt it.  But if you have a large number of these files that need to be converted, you could probably write a little Perl script, or XSLT script to automate the task.

> Also, after changing the configuration will i face any further problem ?

Quite possibly, yes.

---

It does surprise me that the Spring Batch developers changed the schema so late in the development cycle.  And you are entitled to be somewhat miffed ... IMO.  But that's a risk you take when you develop code based on an "Release Candidate".